# Combining Strings into a List in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, split, malloc

Below is my code for the following issue. I'm trying to take a string of first names and string of last names that are separated by commas and transform them into a list of full names. For example, if `firstnames = "John,Jane"` and `lastnames = "Smith,Doe"`, then the output should be `["John Smith", "Jane Doe"]`.

I believe my issue is arising in my use of `strtok` since `first_names[i] = name` is giving me an error. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

```
char **combine_names(char *firstnames, char *lastnames) {
    char first_names[50][50];
    char last_names[50][50];
    int i = 0;
    char *name = strtok(firstnames, ",");
    while (name != NULL) {
        first_names[i] = name;
        i++;
        name = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    i = 0;
    name = strtok(lastnames, ",");
    while (name != NULL) {
        last_names[i] = name;
        i++;
        name = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    char **names;
    names = malloc(strlen(first_names) * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(first_names); i++) {
        names[i] = malloc(51 * sizeof(char));
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (first_names[i] != '\0') {
        while (first_names[i][j] != '\0') {
            names[i][j] = first_names[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        names[i][j] = ' ';
        j++;
        while (second_names[i][k] != '\0') {
            names[i][j] = second_names[i][k];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        names[i][j] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    names[i] = '\0';
    return names;
}
```

The following line is causing an incompatible pointer error with the first argument. Why is that?

```
names = malloc(strlen(first_names) * sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: E.g. `first_names[i]` is an array. You can't assign to an array, but you can [*copy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to it.

Comment: ***And*** `first_names` is not a string, it's not something you can call `strlen` on and expect to get back a valid result. Try to actually *read* the errors and warnings the compiler gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strtok()` does indeed pose some problems, but the main issue is your allocating `names` with an invalid expression `malloc(strlen(first_names) * sizeof(char*));`.  `first_names` is not a C string, `strlen(first_names)` does not compute the number of entries in the `first_names` array.

Here is a simpler and safer approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **combine_names(const char *firstnames, const char *lastnames) {
    int n = 0;
    char **names = malloc(sizeof(*names) * (n + 1));
    char *p;

    if (names == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate memory\n");
    }

    while (*firstnames && *lastnames) {
        int len1 = strcspn(firstnames, ",");
        int len2 = strcspn(lastnames, ",");
        int size = len1 + 1 + len2 + 1;
        p = malloc(size);
        if (p == NULL) {
            perror("cannot allocate memory\n");
        }
        snprintf(p, size, "%.*s%s%.*s",
                 len1, firstnames,
                 len1 && len2 ? " " : "",
                 len2, lastnames);
        names = realloc(names, sizeof(*names) * (n + 2));
        if (names == NULL) {
            perror("cannot allocate memory\n");
        }
        names[n++] = p;
        firstnames += len1 + (firstnames[len1] == ',');
        lastnames += len2 + (lastnames[len2] == ',');
    }
    names[n] = NULL;
    return names;
}
```

Comment: `n` is the number of strings in the combined array. This array is allocated to `n + 1` entries for a `NULL` terminator, otherwise there would be no way to tell the caller how many items have been combined. This convention is used in `main()` for the `argv[]` array.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was making it harder than it needed to be.

Comment: Your multi-phase approach was hardcoding an implicit maximum number of combinations and name lengths. It takes some practice to think in terms of parallel incremental solutions. Sometimes they are difficult to implement, sometimes impossible.  In this case, there is some inefficiency at reallocating the array for each new combination, but simplicity is a cardinal value and unless your input strings are **very** long, this incremental solution is good enough.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that `first_names` is a double array of characters. That means that `first_names[i]` is actually a string, or an array of characters. You can't assign directly to an array of characters, instead you have to write to the array character by character. The easiest way to do this is using string copy or
`strcpy(first_names[i], name)`, but strcpy doesn't protect against buffer overflows. One method is to use `strncpy`, just be careful because this will not guarantee the string is null-terminated when the source string exceeds the size of the destination string. To fix this, use

```
strncpy(first_names[i], name, 50);
first_names[i][49] = '\0';
```

Considering the disadvantages of `strncpy` it's probably best to use a solution similar to @chqrlie.

Comment: `strncpy` will not null terminate the destination if the source is too long, leading to problems. This function is error prone, **do not use it**.  See https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: The links posted do not address the issues of `strncpy`.  The `memset` is redundant, `first_names[i][49] = '\0';` would suffice. newbie programmers should be warned loudly about this error prone function. **do not use it casually**. Read this: https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/

Comment: @chqrlie, Was fixing that as you said it, sorry I'm a bit new to this, just proposing one method of solving it, I would discourage against strncpy as well considering its pitfalls.

Comment: `first_names[49] = '\0'` -> `first_names[i][49] = '\0';`.  *To be safe, you could use strncpy* is not a statement of discouragement.

Comment: @chqrlie Edited, thanks for taking the time to review.